# How to retain last modification date on draft edit

Tags: post-editor

I have a number of drafts on my site created by a third party tool. I now want to publish these drafts. When I do, I want to set the published date on these posts to the last modification date (i.e. the date they were created by the third party tool).

When I edit these drafts, the publication date is automatically set to "Immediately". Without noting the last modification date manually, is there anyway I can set the "published date" to the last modification date, when I first edit each draft?

I have dbase access - could I do this with a query?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to set the status to pending so that you could set the publish date without publishing it?

Comment: That might work going forwards but I need to do this reterospectively.

Comment: that might be easier than you think, especially if you have an easy test for wether the post was created by that third party tool, it might even be easier than the solution to your question. You should open a new question asking how to do that, where's the harm in finding out how?